# Find all combinations of 3 in a column (player_name), grouped by another column (team_name + match_id) and count instances of each combo

Tags: r, combinations

I've been teaching myself some R by playing with different sports stats and I've hit a wall.

```
match_id    player_name player_team points
Match1  Player 1    Team 1  20
Match1  Player 2    Team 1  23
Match1  Player 3    Team 1  24
Match1  Player 4    Team 2  26
Match1  Player 5    Team 2  21
Match1  Player 6    Team 2  22
Match1  Player 7    Team 2  43
Match1  Player 8    Team 2  38
Match2  Player 9    Team 3  24
Match2  Player 10   Team 3  29
Match2  Player 11   Team 3  23
Match2  Player 12   Team 3  22
Match2  Player 13   Team 4  20
Match2  Player 14   Team 4  32
Match3  Player 15   Team 5  24
Match3  Player 16   Team 5  27
Match3  Player 17   Team 5  23
Match3  Player 18   Team 5  20
Match3  Player 19   Team 5  23
```

The data continues through out the season, so teams and players repeat as it goes on.
I'm trying to take the above and find all combinations of 3 different players for the same team, who get 20 or more points in a match (points is already filtered to only include 20+), then find how many matches each combination appears in so as to tell me which group of 3 players on the same team frequently score 20+ when they play together.

As some players on different teams have the same name, I've used mutate to combine player_team and player_name as well as combining player_team and match_id just because some attempts ended up combining players from different teams.

The closest I've been able to get was by using the code below but it only works for combinations of 2.

```
data <- players %>%
  filter(disposals >= 20)

data <- data %>%
  select(match_id, player_name, player_team)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(match_id = paste(player_team, match_id, sep = "_"))%>%
  mutate(player_name = paste(player_team, player_name, sep = "_"))

data <- data %>%
  select(match_id, player_name)

dataout <- get.data.frame(
  graph_from_adjacency_matrix(
    crossprod(table(data)),
    mode = "directed",
    weighted = TRUE,
    diag = FALSE,
  )
)
```

Which gives me the below (weight is based on occurrences through entire data set rather than example above which so far has each team playing 3 games)

| from | to | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Team 1_Player 1 | Team 1_Player 2 | 1 |
| Team 1_Player 1 | Team 1_Player 3 | 3 |
| Team 1_Player 2 | Team 1_Player 3 | 1 |
| Team 2_Player 4 | Team 2_Player 5 | 2 |
| Team 2_Player 4 | Team 2_Player 6 | 1 |
| Team 2_Player 4 | Team 2_Player 7 | 3 |
| Team 2_Player 4 | Team 2_Player 8 | 3 |
| Team 2_Player 5 | Team 2_Player 6 | 1 |
| Team 2_Player 5 | Team 2_Player 7 | 2 |

Note that combinations do not repeat in all possible orders (ie. recognises that Team 1_Player 1 + Team 1_Player 2 is the same as Team 1_Player 2 + Team 1_Player 1)

Is there any other solution which would allow me to include three players (or more) instead of just two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `combn(m = 3)` to get all possible triples:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~match_id, ~player_name, ~team_name, ~points,
   "Match1",           1L,         1L,     20L,
   "Match1",           2L,         1L,     23L,
   "Match1",           3L,         1L,     24L,
   "Match1",           4L,         2L,     26L,
   "Match1",           5L,         2L,     21L,
   "Match1",           6L,         2L,     22L,
   "Match1",           7L,         2L,     43L,
   "Match1",           8L,         2L,     38L,
   "Match2",           9L,         3L,     24L,
   "Match2",          10L,         3L,     29L,
   "Match2",          11L,         3L,     23L,
   "Match2",          12L,         3L,     22L,
   "Match2",          13L,         4L,     20L,
   "Match2",          14L,         4L,     32L,
   "Match3",          15L,         5L,     24L,
   "Match3",          16L,         5L,     27L,
   "Match3",          17L,         5L,     23L,
   "Match3",          18L,         5L,     20L,
   "Match3",          19L,         5L,     23L
  )

combinations_data <-
  data %>%
  filter(points >= 20) %>%
  nest(-c(team_name, match_id)) %>%
  mutate(
    combinations = data %>% map(possibly(~ {
      .x$player_name %>% unique() %>% combn(3)
    }, NA))
  )
#> Warning: All elements of `...` must be named.
#> Did you want `data = -c(team_name, match_id)`?

combinations_data %>%
  filter(match_id == "Match1" & team_name == 2) %>%
  pull(combinations) %>%
  first()
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#> [1,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    5    5    5     6
#> [2,]    5    5    5    6    6    7    6    6    7     7
#> [3,]    6    7    8    7    8    8    7    8    8     8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

There are 10 unique combinations of players of team 2 in Match1 which all scored higher than 20.

Comment: Thanks, this allows me to see all the different combinations which is really useful.

Is it possible to then take the combinations_data and create a df where the columns would be something like value1, value2, value3 (where each value is player_name) so that it displays each possible combination as a row?

Comment: Sure. You can convert the matrix to a rowwise data frame using `.x$player_name %>% unique() %>% combn(3) %>% t() %>% as_tibble()`

Comment: Thanks, this works and allows me to then output the combinations list as a df. I just had to arrange the data by player_name so that I didn't have the same combination of players repeat in different orders for the same match. Thanks for your help.